# Optimize Random Forest parameters in weka?

Tags: java, machine-learning, parameters, weka, random-forest

I am trying to optimize random forest parameters using weka, the java class is as the following:

```
package pkg10foldcrossvalidation;

import weka.core.*;
import weka.classifiers.meta.*;
import weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest;
import java.io.*;
public class RF_Optimizer {



     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      // load data
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Prediction Results on the testing set\\Dataset.arff"));
      Instances data = new Instances(reader);
      reader.close();
      data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

      // setup classifier
      CVParameterSelection ps = new CVParameterSelection();
      ps.setClassifier(new RandomForest());
      ps.setNumFolds(10);  // using 10-fold CV
      ps.addCVParameter("C 0.1 0.5 5");

      // build and output best options
      ps.buildClassifier(data);
      System.out.println(Utils.joinOptions(ps.getBestClassifierOptions()));
   }

}
```

But I am facing difficulty of understanding which parameters should replace the "C" and how the range of each one could be determined? And is it workable to use `.addCVParameter` several times for several parameters at the same time?

I tried to search for some youtube or website tutorials that explain how to change random forest parameters in java but nothing found.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing, `-C` are the Cross-Validation parameters, not the RandomForest parameters.

Can't you just use the Explorer GUI, open a sample dataset such as `glass.arff`, and then right-click on the bold **RandomForest** string at the top of the window, then from the context menu choose "copy configuration to clipboard", and then paste that string into your java code?

After doing this right now, I've copied this string to the clipboard:

`weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest -P 100 -I 100 -num-slots 1 -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1`

These are the default parameters for Weka's RandomForest learner. What these parameters mean, and which of them is most suitable for optimization, and which range of values to use for optimization I really can't tell. Most likely a very important parameter is `numIterations`, the `-I` parameter. Maybe vary it from 100, 200,... to 1000 and plot numIterations vs Accuracy, and check if the curve has smoothed out already.